# Error building iOS project with Jenkins on MacOS X Lione

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, revision

Jenkins successfully manages to checkout the project from BitBucket but after that I get this error message:

> Started by user anonymous
>
> Building in workspace
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/myprojectAdHocBuild/workspace
>
> Checkout:workspace /
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/myprojectAdHocBuild/workspace -
>   hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@xxxxxxx
>
> Using strategy: Default
>
> Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
>
> Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:myuser/myproject.git
>
> No candidate revisions
>
> ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and
>   branch configuration for this job.
>
> Archiving artifacts
>
> Finished: FAILURE

Any idea how to fix it?